# Proxying Jira with Apache results in broken Pages

Tags: apache, jira

As soon as I use an Apache Server for proxiyng my existing 7.3.1 Jira Installation it only shows broken pages and for the Jira Startup it doesnt refresh the page automatically.

If I open Jira in the browser via the base URL it works like charme. Even on the Jira Startup it refrehes automatically and shows the current status of Jira e.g. the loading of add-ons and stuff.

Is it possible that Apache is blocking some parts of the jira page?

For the apache I have used a distribution from here: [Apachehaus.com](http://www.apachehaus.com)
And for the set up I have used the following steps from Atlassian: [Link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver072/integrating-jira-with-apache-using-ssl-828788158.html)

Why are the page shown broken via apache but not for the Base URL of Jira?

Answer (score 1):

i use jira behind apache with mod_proxy and ajp since a couple of years with no issues.

- At first i disabled gzip-compression in the jira-settings
- in the server xml of the jira-installation i modified the context-path of jira from "/" to "/jira"
- i also enabled the ajp-connector on port 9008
  `<Connector port="9008" redirectPort="8443" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />`
- At last a snippet of my httpd.conf (from within a VirtualHost-Tag)

  ```
  # mount jira
  ProxyPass /jira ajp://localhost:9008/jira timeout=60
  ProxyPassReverse /jira ajp://localhost:9008/jira
  ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It was way more complicated to identify but the problem was the browser I used which was the IE 11. It was configured to handle the site as a non-trusted site. Which maybe turned off all the fancy Jira-things which need to be executable by the site... I fixed it and afterwards burned it down. Thanks anyway ;)